Google Password Manager in WebView is asking for username but not in Chrome
We are running a Website and an App. Our App is just a WebView which is loading HTML pages. The registration page is using a simple form login, which is simple HTML. In essence it looks like this:
<form id="benutzerAnlegenForm" class="formnew" 
      novalidate="novalidate" 
      action="/info/profil/registrierung" 
      method="post"
      accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div class="formwrapper">
        <div class="formrow">
            <div class="formlabel"><label for="emailadresse">E-Mail</label></div>
            <div class="formfield">
                <div class="forminput">
                  
                  <input id="emailadresse" name="emailadresse" 
                         autocomplete="username" 
                         type="email"
                         value="" size="30" maxlength="80">

                </div>
                <div class="formhelp">[... helptext ...]</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formrow">
            <div class="formlabel"><label for="passwort">Passwort</label></div>
            <div class="formfield">
                <div class="forminput">

                <input id="passwort" name="passwort" 
                       autocomplete="new-password" 
                       type="password"
                       value="" size="30" maxlength="80">

                 </div>
                <div class="formhelp">[... helptext ...]</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formrow">
            <div class="formfield formsubmit">
              <input type="hidden" name="_charset_" value="">
              <input name="submitbutton" type="submit"                                                                                                       
                     value="Jetzt registrieren!">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

It is online here:
https://www.kicktipp.de/info/profil/registrierung
I am using for my test a Google Pixel 7a with Android 14.
When I visit this page with Mobile Google Chrome: after entering a username it offers me "Suggest Strong password" and I can accept it and I am done:

If I open the same page in WebView I have a different user experience as the password manager asks me to enter the username into the modal:

this is annoying as I have entered the username already into the form. How can I fix this behavior or is it not possible because of the WebView technology?
